# Laravel 5 json response array

Tags: php, laravel

I followed a tutorial on `Laravel` and `AngularJS` and trying to convert a `public function` to laravel 5. The code is this:

```
public function store()
    {
        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => Input::get('author'),
            'text' => Input::get('text')
        ));

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }
```

I converted it with this:

```
public function store()
    {
        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => Request::get('author'),
            'text' => Request::get('text')
        ));
    }
```

Now, how about the line `return Response::json(array('success' => true))`? How can I convert it to Laravel 5? Thank you.

Comment: In laravel 5 if you just return an array it will show up in output as json, so just return array('success' => true); would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by converting to Laravel 5, this line of code itself is valid Laravel 5 code, but you can leverage nice helper function Laravel 5 provides:

```
return response()->json([
    'success' => true
]);
```